# remove all pushpins windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Im trying to remove all the pushpins from the map and its not removing them (nothing is happening) , any help   would be appreciated

```
 private void Remove_all_PushPins_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      MessageBoxResult m =  MessageBox.Show("All PushPins will be deleted", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
      if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
      {
          foreach (UIElement element in map1.Children)
          {
              if (element.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin))
              {
                     map1.Children.Remove(element);
              }  
          }

       }

  }
```

Comment: have you tried `map1.Children.Clear()`? also, how did you add the Pushpins to the Map?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out spomething simpler i think,
  made a new layer only for the pushpins:

```
MapLayer pushpin_layer = new MapLayer();
```

add pushpins to that layer:

```
pushpin_layer.Children.Add(random_point);
```

add remove  the children (pushpins) of that layer:

```
 private void Remove_all_PushPins_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          MessageBoxResult m =  MessageBox.Show("All PushPins will be deleted", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
          if (m == MessageBoxResult.OK)
          {
                  pushpin_layer.Children.Clear();
          }

      }
```

Comment: Not simpler, just difference in context. Later on you might end up with more elements ('Children') in this layer and then you want to select which ones to remove. So you will end up with code similar to @Oren's above :)

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the pre-WP8 Map control since the WP8 version doesn't have a `Children` property. The main issue that I see in your code is that you are modifying the `Children` collection while iterating through it, which should throw an `InvalidOperationException`.

I've mocked up some code based on your sample that should work:

```
    private void myMap_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        // removal queue for existing pins
        var toRemove = new List<UIElement>();

        // iterate through all children that are PushPins. Could also use a Linq selector
        foreach (var child in myMap.Children)
        {
            if (child is Pushpin)
            {
                // queue this child for removal
                toRemove.Add(child);
            }
        }

        // now do the actual removal
        foreach (var child in toRemove)
        {
            myMap.Children.Remove(child);
        }

        // now add in 10 new PushPins
        var rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var pin = new Pushpin();

            pin.Location = new System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinate() { Latitude = rand.Next(90), Longitude = rand.Next(-180, 180) };

            myMap.Children.Add(pin);
        }

    }
```